# Is Kali Linux 2 broken?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, linux-kernel

This might be just on my part but I really doubt that. I'm running it in persistence from USB, the most notable problems come when trying to login as root, can't it just acknowledges test and even the rate times I manage to get in as root no matter how many times I change the password it returns to toor ... I've also stopped being able to boot from startup and have to boot from BIOS, sometime after attempting to log out the system crashes and I'm left in a empty screen with a blinker one time it turned out be shell and I could still type commands I just couldn't do anything with a gui....Has any one else also experienced this?

Comment: Sorry I write these fast on my phone. . Unfortunately I don't know how to do 1337 speak yet

Answer (score 1):

Persistence on Kali linux live USB's is not a 'one-click' option and requires previous setup. Please refer to official Kali linux documentation to learn more;

http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence

Written out;

You’ll need to have root privileges to do this procedure, or the ability to escalate your privileges with the command “sudo su”. In this example, we assume

- you are running as the root user
- your USB drive is /dev/sdb
- your USB drive has a capacity of at least 8GB — the Kali Linux image 
  takes over 3GB, and for this guide, we’ll be creating a new partition
  of about 4GB to store our persistent data in.

In this example, we’ll create a new partition to store our persistent data into, starting right above the second Kali Live partition and ending at 7GB, put an ext3 file system onto it, and create a persistence.conf file on the new partition.

First, begin by imaging the latest Kali Linux ISO (currently v1.0.9a) to your USB drive as described in this article. We’re going to assume that the two partitions created by the imaging are /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2.

```
This can be verified with the command “fdisk -l“.
```

Create and format an additional partition on the USB drive.
First, let’s create the new partition in the empty space above our Kali Live partitions.

```
end=7gb
read start _ < <(du -bcm kali-linux-1.0.8-amd64.iso | tail -1); echo $start
parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary $start $end
```

The parted command may advise you that it can’t use the exact start values you specified; if so, accept the suggested value instead. If advised that the partition isn’t placed at an optimal location, “ignore” it. When parted completes, the new partition should have been created at /dev/sdb3; again, this can be verified with the command

```
fdisk -l
```

Next, create an ext3 file system in the partition and label it “persistence”.

```
mkfs.ext3 -L persistence /dev/sdb3
e2label /dev/sdb3 persistence
```

Create a mount point, mount the new partition there, and then create the configuration file to enable persistence. Finally, unmount the partition.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb
mount /dev/sdb3 /mnt/my_usb
echo "/ union" > /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf
umount /dev/sdb3
```

Comment: @fixer1234 Fixed ;P